# K2 User show total number of Item hits

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, k2

I have a requirement where I want to show the total number of hits that a user's items have been read. For example, if they have ten K2 items, each have been read 10 times, then I want to show the total number (in this case 100) of hits that users total items have been read.

K2 has a variable, which I can echo for each of the items:

```
<?php echo $item->hits; ?>
```

But I need a way to add all of the authors items hits up.

** Update **

So I'm thinking, could this be done using a SQL query? Something similar to:

```
SELECT count('hits') FROM #__k2_items WHERE authorid='id';
```

Comment: a small change in your query must be there: instead of count take `sum('hits')` . check with this if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->qn('hits'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__k2_items'))
      ->where($db->qn('created_by') . ' = ' . $db->q($this->user->id));
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

$sum = 0;
foreach ($results as $key => $val)
{
    $sum+= $val->hits;
}

echo number_format($sum);
```

Simple database query that returns that hits for all articles created by the author of the current article being views.

It that adds each of the values in a `foreach` loop and displays the result.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just tried that, but it's returning 0 when echoing $sum

Comment: Did you use the updated code? I ended up editing my answer quite a lot when I submitted it. I'm not sure where you're adding the code, by I tried in `components\com_k2\templates\default\item.php` with the code in my answer and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: It should be noted that this code should be written as a plugin and NOT added to your component's `user.php` file or module's `authors.php` file. This prevents SQL from running in your templates. If you would rather add code to your templates, there is another way using K2's reference variables, similar to your first suggestion.